# Prevent loading of tcltk package

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've been googling this for a while, and I've found 3 or 4 threads on this topic on StackOverflow but they don't seem to answer at all the question or I didn't understand the answers. I'm running the **multicore** package and I know it has problems with tcl/tk. I want to run R without loading **tcltk**, but cant seem to find out how to do it. I've tried:

```
R --no-save

R --vanilla
```

Not sure how to disable it in any other way.

Comment: It's a package. If you don't load it is won't be used.

Comment: I know, but it gets automatically loaded when I use certain libraries. Even though I directly never use tk/tcl

Comment: "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this.". "Then don't do it."  You need to deal with the cause, ie why those packages load the tcltk package.

Comment: if you MUST know, even though these packages use tcl, they dont require them, they can be run without them. These packages dont have the option to not load tcl/tk. This R script can be run without a problem in servers without loading X11.

Comment: You could start by unsetting `DISPLAY` but then those packages may not load.  At some point, if you want real help, you need to be a little less vague...

Comment: mmm...sorry If I appear vague, but thought it was very specific question, preventing tk/tcl from loading. Unsetting display sounds like a very good diea, never thought about that. Thank you!

Comment: One usual suspect is the gsubfn package that is used by roxygen and sqldf. By default it uses the tcl engine. If you add  options(gsubfn.engine = 'R') at the beginning of your script if will not load the tcl/tk package.